# How to Retrieve Forge Viewer objectTree?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

My goal is to highlight a room by adding new geometry to the viewer based on lines I have created in revit like they do here [Link](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2016/06/highlighting-revit-rooms-in-the-forge-viewer.html#4)

but i can not figure out how to access those lines ids.
I know what they are in revit (element_id) but not how they are mapped as dbid.

Following this [Blog Post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/12/select-all-elements-in-the-viewer-with-view-and-data-api-with-javascript.html)

I want to access the objectTree in my extension to find out, but it always comes back as undefined.

```
var tree;
//old way - viewer is your viewer object - undefined
viewer.getObjectTree(function (objTree) {
 tree = objTree;
});
```

//2.5 - undefined

```
  var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
  var rootId = this.rootId = instanceTree.getRootId();
```

//- undefined

```
  var objectTree = viewer.getObjectTree();
```

Can anyone tell me if its still works for them I am using the v2 of the API for the rvt conversion to svf and 2.9 of the viewer3D.js

note I can see a list of dbid if I call this

```
var model = viewer.impl.model;
var data = model.getData();
var fragId2dbIdArray = data.fragments.fragId2dbId ;
```

but have no way of mapping back to the Revit element_id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of version 2.9 this is still working. Here's my console:
[image: Console log]

Here's a couple of things you can try:

1. Is `viewer` undefined? Are you in the correct scope when grabbing the `viewer`?
2. The document have to be loaded before you can grab the instance tree. When the document is loaded, an event called `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` will be fired, then you can start manipulating the instance tree.

Simply do this:

```
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function () {
var instanceTree = viewer.model.getData().instanceTree;
});
```

For more structured code, follow [this guide](https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/viewer/v2/tutorials/extensions/) to add an extension.

There's a [more detailed blog post](http://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2015/08/asynchronous-viewer-events-notification.html) on which event to listen for. It's still using the old way to get instance tree, though.

Answer (score 3):

Shiya Luo was correct the viewer had not yet finished loading the geometry

in my extentions Load function I added two event listeners and made sure they both fired before trying to access the instanceTree

```
 viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT, function () {
    finishedGEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT = true;
    if(finishedGEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT && finishedOBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT ){
        afterModelLoadEvents(viewer);
    }
 });
viewer.addEventListener(Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT, function () {
    finishedOBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT = true;
    if(finishedGEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT && finishedOBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT ){
        afterModelLoadEvents(viewer);           
    }
 });
```