# How to get the model object tree of 2D drawing

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I use `viewer.getObjectTree = function(onSuccessCallback, onErrorCallback)` to get the model object tree, then traverse from the root node down to all leaf nodes. Here is the code:

```
viewer.getObjectTree(function (objTree) {
    objTree.enumNodeChildren(
        objTree.getRootId(),
        function (dbId) {
            // Work with dbId
        },
        true
    );
};
```

However, it works only for 3D model. 2D model does not jump into the callback events. How can I get all object Ids of a 2D layout/drawing?

Comment: I just verified with our sample Revit file, and use a 2D model in Viewer 2.11, it works fine.

For your issue, usually, the reason is that the instance tree is not initialized when you try to get it. So you need to make sure the instance tree is already set up. Did you check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38904993/how-to-retrieve-forge-viewer-objecttree/38909765#38909765 in case it's the same issue?

Comment: I put the `viewer.getObjectTree` inside `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` but it did not work for 2D drawing, only 3D model. Could you please share your full code.

Comment: Did you try to do it inside Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT? I actually made it inside this event.

Comment: I tried to load `viewer.getObjectTree` inside both `Autodesk.Viewing.GEOMETRY_LOADED_EVENT` and  `Autodesk.Viewing.OBJECT_TREE_CREATED_EVENT` but nothing works. You can try to load a urn of a specific 2D layout of the main 3D model.

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason. 2D layout/drawing does not have its model object tree (just layers). It uses different data structure with 3D model. 3D uses an instance tree to get all nodes, but 2D uses a string of DbIds.

To navigate objects in 3D model, use `viewer.getObjectTree` and `viewer.model.getData().instanceTree`.

To navigate objects in 2D layout, use `viewer.model.getData()`. I can get a list of DbIds from `viewer.model.getData().stringDbIds`

Comment: `viewer.model.getData().stringDbIds` does not return correct DbIds used in the 2D drawing.

Comment: What's the format of your seed file? Is that a DWG file?

Comment: My seed file is 2D DWF. DWG would be the same.